# Apply cohomology base change theorem to Projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise in Vakil's FOAG,page 711
[image]

I don't know how to use the Cohomology and Base Change Theorem,becasue if we want to use the theorem,we need to show that the base change morphism $\phi_q^0:pr_1{_*}(\mathscr L )\otimes k(q)\to H^0(X\times\mathbb P^n|_q,\mathscr L|_{X\times\mathbb P^n|_q})$ is surjective for every point $q$ in $X$,which in this situation means that there is a section of $\mathscr L$ over $\mathbb P^n_A$ not vanish over the fiber of $q$ for some affine open subset $Spec A$ around  $q$,which is not clear to me.

Comment: What exactly are the terms in $\phi^0_q$? Is the codomain considered as a $k(q)$-vector space? If so, how is $pr_{1,*}\mathscr{L}$ considered as a $k(q)$-vector space (or a module over, say, some ring $A$ corresponding to a neighborhood of $q$)? Is it the set of stalks of the sheaf at $q$? Its set of "global sections" on a given affine subset of $X$? Or is $\phi^0_q$ regarded as a morphism of sheaves, the codomain of which has support only on $q$?

Comment: For the end -- note that the "natural map" is a morphism of invertible sheaves, so it is an isomorphism iff it is surjective. By Nakayama, it is surjective iff it is surjective on the tensor product of stalks with the residual fields.

Comment: The domain of $\phi^0_q$ is considered as a pull back of the natural map $Speck(q)\to X$ of $pr_{1,*}\mathscr{L}$ ,since $Speck(q)$ is affine,it is same as a module,i.e. a vector space over $k(q)$.The codomain is the cohomology(Cech) of restriction of $\mathscr L$ on the fiber of q which is also same as a vector space over k(q).The map between them is built from FHHF(which says there is always a natural map when commutes cohomology and left or right exact functor).